# Distinguishing between machines with client credentials flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

It seemed like `client_credentials` flow was appropriate for a machine-to-machine communication between our system and third parties for importing and exporting data.

But if I have two third parties `p` and `q` say and users on our system `u` and `v` say, then I need to know which of `p` and `q` can acces the data of which of `u` and `v`.

For example: user `u` grants access to `p` (but not to `q`) and `v` to `q` (but not `p`).

I can give different client secrets to `p` and `q` but when they present thir secret to IdentityServer in order to obtain a token I need to know *which* of `p` and `q` it is and add a claim to the token that my controllers can use to determine which of `u` ad `v`'s data is visible.

I can implement `ICustomTokenRequestValidator` to intercept the secret and look it up in the configuration context, but the `Id` column is not in the model class, so I could abuse the `Description` column as a foreign key to my table of third parties -- seems hacky.

Is there a standard/recommended way to resolve this situation -- that different machines have different data visible to them (different claims in their token)?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `client_credentials` flow then there is no user-interaction involved.

Each third party should have it's own client with corresponding client credentials. Do not share the same credentials over boundaries, i.e. between different third parties. By having separate clients for separate parties, you minimize the security risk and minimize the impact when having to revoke or change the credentials.

With that said, in the Client Credentials flow the Authorization Server returns a token if the request is valid - it does not know from the request if the user authorized the request or not because the user is not involved. But it authenticates the client. So, if you want to differentiate between several third parties, give them individual clients. If you can't add a claim to the token.

Scopes and claims are the tools to define what a client requests to do. Some authorization can be done in the Authorization Server. For example, an Authorization Server typically only allows a client to request certain scopes.

Use then claims (the data in the token) for a fine grained authorization in the API. It depends on your use case. If the API is supposed to return a filtered result, i.e. only return data from users that are ok with it, then the API needs to be able to look this information up somewhere, as @gary-archer states. Use an applicable claim from the token that enables the API to identify the client or third party. It can then use this data for the lookup. For example, use the `client_id` claim but it really depends on the Authorization Server which claims it adds to the token.

If the client already knows beforehand which user's data it is going to access, it could add the user-id when requesting the token and - once again - depending on the capabilities of the Authorization Server - get a token with a `user_id` in the claim set. Then the API can use the `client_id` and `user_id` for a lookup.

How you collect the users' consent is out of scope and happens out of bound. It's part of your business logic.

At the end it is all about designing the token. Here is another article on Centralizing Identity Data

Answer (score 0):

The standard option here is to include custom claims from your business data at the time of token issuance. Rather than `machine to machine` I would describe your scenario as `B2B`.

**EXAMPLE USE CASE**

Consider an API called by business partners who act as suppliers of inventory to your system. In this case a useful access token might look like this, and is what I would aim for:

```json
{
client_id: 1hvf367g
supplier_id: 42
exp: ...
}
```

API requests for stock items could then authorize based on the `supplier_id` value in the access token. Eg by running a SQL query on the business data, filtering on the supplier ID. All of this keeps your API code simple.

**DATA MAPPING**

For this to work you need to design onboarding. Eg a button click to create a supplier in your system might create the OAuth client using Identity Server, then save the client_id to a suppliers table in the business data.

Not all identity systems support issuing custom claims in the above manner. An alternative design is to just include the `client_id` in the access token, and look up the supplier ID from business data when your API receives an access token. This tends to add complexity to API code though.

**SUMMARY**

I think your question is really about designing business permissions, and OAuth alone cannot solve it. If I'm right then the [Claims Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/) article may be useful.

Comment: So you're saying that a client -- rather than a client secret -- is what corresponds to the external thing?

Comment: Each external 'thing', or 'business partner,' is configured as a separate OAuth client that can be managed separately. During HTTP requests to the Identity Server they are authenticated and identified by the client ID + client secret. During API requests with access tokens you will then authorize using claims from your business data. So there are two parts to the overall solution.

Comment: Unfortunately that's infeasible in IdentityServer5 which is limited to 5 clients unless you cough up megabucks.